# SQL INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE Queries With PyODBC

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

```
import pyodbc

cnxn_str = ("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
            "Server=#.#.#.#;"
            "Database=DataBase;"
            "PORT=1433;"
            "UID=xxx;"
           
            "PWD=xxx;")
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)
//connect to sql database using connection string
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

sn_query ="SELECT **"
cursor.execute(sn_query)
//execute the select query 
for row in cursor:
    num= row[0]

print(num)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
//execute the insert query
insert_bool_query ="INSERT into Table(name) values("The name you wan to insert");

cursor.execute(insert_bool_query)
for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

So I want to know whether if I can execute Select query, insert query and update query using only cursor.execute. In addition, if yes, then how to extract the rows for each query?

Comment: What do you mean to excecute them at the same time?

Comment: I mean I want to get the value of the column using select query. After that, I will update value to one of the column from table using update query. Then I will insert boolean value to table. However, as you saw, cursor.execute is the same for all 3 tasks. So I am not sure when cursor.excute is run, it will not do all the things I mentioned before. I will edit my question also. Thank you.